# OpenCV Calibration error when using video file

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I was trying to use a video file for camera calibration using the sample camera_calibration.cpp that comes with opencv and I got this error:

```
 OpenCV Error: Parsing error (calibration/calibration.mp4(0): Too long string or a last string w/o newline) in icvXMLSkipSpaces
```

This is the input line in the XML file:

```
<Input>"calibration/calibration.mp4"</Input>
```

Comment: Sounds like you're possibly using the wrong function (that's many to load saved calibration data). Show us some code.

Comment: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/calib3d/camera_calibration This is the link to the code. It is too long to copy and paste into the textbox.

Comment: You have edited the input XML file, right? Because what you are seeing is an XML parsing error. Can you edit your question to include the input XML file you were trying to use?